# Splitting dataframe to train and test set

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I want to split my data frame into a train and test set.
I tried the following:

```
library(caret)
train.index <- createDataPartition(dataframe$id, p = .81, list = FALSE)
#createDataPartition does half of what I want
```

I also tried it with time slices but the solution I want is none of them.
I need to get the same percentage of every id in my data frame for training and test set. The code above works but here comes my problem:
 I need to split multiple successive rows, so normal random split does not work for me. I need to get always a specific amount of rows as one test case because I want to use a neural network to identify the id.

Example data frame (note: all .. are actually filled):

```
id   bla  blu  and  so  on
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  3
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  2
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  1
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  1
 2   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 2   ...  ...  ...  ..  1
 2   ...  ...  ...  ..  3
 2   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 3   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 3   ...  ...  ...  ..  33
 3   ...  ...  ...  ..  16
 3   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
 3   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..
```

The solution for the test set (rest is training set):

```
id   bla  blu  and  so  on

 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  3
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  2
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  1
 1   ...  ...  ...  ..  1
 2   ...  ...  ...  ..  1
 2   ...  ...  ...  ..  3
 3   ...  ...  ...  ..  33
 3   ...  ...  ...  ..  16
```

So, I got random chunks from my dataset with length = 2 (each). Those are successive rows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Do you need to sample on a percentage of unique ID values, instead of rows in the data frame?

Comment: Please specify the algorithm for splitting, provide reproducible example and what you've tried so far that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Yes since I have different amount of rows for each id. it has to be the same percentage which is to be used for training and test set. The createDataPartition function does that perfectly but I need n-chunks of rows like:take 5 successive rows till your test set is 19% of data and bind together. so my test set wouldn't be completly random but random chunks of my initial dataframe.

Comment: Are you saying that for each ID value, you want x% in the training data set, and 1-x% in the test data set? What should happen if the count of ID values isn't equally divisible by the sampling percentage? Is each ID measured the same number of times?

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to randomly partition the data by ID, one can split the data by ID, apply the `createDataPartition()` function, and reassemble the split data into test and training data sets as follows.

```
 # split IDs and sample half to test and half to training
 # create 450 rows of random data with non-random ID assignment
 df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),nrow=100,ncol=10))
 df1$id <- 1:100
 df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(3500),nrow=350,ncol=10))
 df2$id <- c(1:100,rep(1:2,125))
 theData <- rbind(df1,df2)
 theData$id <- as.factor(theData$id)
 dataList <- split(theData,theData$id)
 library(caret)
 set.seed(950146187)
 trainAndTest <- lapply(dataList,function(x){
      trainIndex <- createDataPartition(x$id,p=.5,list=FALSE)
      training <- x[trainIndex,]
      testing <- x[-trainIndex,]
      # return a list() containing both test and train data frames
      list(training=training,testing=testing)
 })
 # combine training sets to one data frame
 training <- do.call(rbind,lapply(trainAndTest,function(x){x[["training"]]}))
 # combine testing data sets to one data frame
 testing <- do.call(rbind,lapply(trainAndTest,function(x){x[["testing"]]}))
 # show approximately 50% of 450 are in each data set
 nrow(testing)
 nrow(training)
```

...and the output:

```
> nrow(testing)
[1] 224
> nrow(training)
[1] 226
>
```

Comment: This solution is what I got myself, but I need something else here. Its almost the same. What we have to change is just that I need X-successive rows for testcases. like if row number 16 is chosen, then i need to put row 16 till 16+x-1 into the testset. the percentage which is used in createDataPartition(...p=0.5) does not have to be met perfectly. almost 50% in this case would also be ok.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for based on your comment. It's too ambiguous. Please modify your original post to make it clear what you're requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution involving newest addition to `tidyverse` family `rsample` by @topepo:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(rsample)

test_window <- 2

ordered_mtcars <- mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
  # lets assume cyl represents group id, as in your example
  rename(id=cyl) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  # we will generate sequence id to mimic the "time" aspect of data
  mutate(ordr=seq(n())) %>% ungroup()
```

We will use `mtcars` dataset with small modifications to illustrate the sampling method

```
samples_df <- ordered_mtcars %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% nest() %>% 
  # we will generate a bunch of samples the size of target window. 
  # initial = 1 ensures that we have samples from every "time segment" of the data
  # skip ensures samples are non-overlapping
  mutate(idx=map(data, rolling_origin, initial=1, assess=test_window, skip=test_window-1)) %>% 
  # we are only interested in "testing" samples
  unnest(idx) %>% mutate(r_test=map(splits, testing))

  head(samples_df) 
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id       splits    id1            r_test
#>   <dbl>       <list>  <chr>            <list>
#> 1     4 <S3: rsplit> Slice1 <tibble [2 x 12]>
#> 2     4 <S3: rsplit> Slice2 <tibble [2 x 12]>
#> 3     4 <S3: rsplit> Slice3 <tibble [2 x 12]>
#> 4     4 <S3: rsplit> Slice4 <tibble [2 x 12]>
#> 5     4 <S3: rsplit> Slice5 <tibble [2 x 12]>
#> 6     6 <S3: rsplit> Slice1 <tibble [2 x 12]>
```

Lets calculate which fraction of the samples_df is represented by 1 sampling window (by group). We will sample this many groups to make sure smalles of our groups has at least one sampling bunch.

```
frac <- samples_df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(frac=1/n()) %>% pull(frac) %>% max

  # here we are sampling bunches per group, so that we draw exactly 1 bunch from the smallest group
ordered_mtcars_test <- samples_df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  sample_frac(size = frac) %>% 
  unnest(r_test) %>% 
  arrange(id, ordr) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  select(names(ordered_mtcars))

  ordered_mtcars_test
#> # A tibble: 10 x 13
#>              rowname   mpg    id  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  ordr
#>                <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1    Toyota Corolla  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1     6
#>  2     Toyota Corona  21.5     4 120.1    97  3.70 2.465 20.01     1     0     3     1     7
#>  3      Lotus Europa  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77 1.513 16.90     1     1     5     2    10
#>  4        Volvo 142E  21.4     4 121.0   109  4.11 2.780 18.60     1     1     4     2    11
#>  5         Merc 280C  17.8     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.90     1     0     4     4     6
#>  6      Ferrari Dino  19.7     6 145.0   175  3.62 2.770 15.50     0     1     5     6     7
#>  7 Chrysler Imperial  14.7     8 440.0   230  3.23 5.345 17.42     0     0     3     4     8
#>  8  Dodge Challenger  15.5     8 318.0   150  2.76 3.520 16.87     0     0     3     2     9
#>  9  Pontiac Firebird  19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2    12
#> 10    Ford Pantera L  15.8     8 351.0   264  4.22 3.170 14.50     0     1     5     4    13
```

Training portion of the data is just whatever did not end up in the test set

```
ordered_mtcars_train <-  ordered_mtcars %>% 
  anti_join(ordered_mtcars_test, by=c("id", "ordr"))

ordered_mtcars_train
#> # A tibble: 22 x 13
#>           rowname   mpg    id  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  ordr
#>             <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     Datsun 710  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1     1
#>  2      Merc 240D  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2     2
#>  3       Merc 230  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2     3
#>  4       Fiat 128  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1     4
#>  5    Honda Civic  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2     5
#>  6      Fiat X1-9  27.3     4  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1     8
#>  7  Porsche 914-2  26.0     4 120.3    91  4.43 2.140 16.70     0     1     5     2     9
#>  8      Mazda RX4  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4     1
#>  9  Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4     2
#> 10 Hornet 4 Drive  21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1     3
```